# how can i populate array elements from an external file

Tags: javascript

```
var a1=[[]];

jQuery.get('file.txt', function(data) {
  a1=data;
  console.log(a1);
});
```

//file.txt contains data as follows

[[0,'IN',2],[1,'142',3]]

now my question is   `a1=data` in above code is not an array like `var a=[[0,'IN,2],[2,'142'3]];`how can i populate array elements from a text file???

Comment: Or just use `$.getJSON`

Comment: it's not a json file simply a text file

Comment: If it's not JSON, you'll need to write your own parser..  To help, we'd have to know the exact format of the data.

Comment: If you can trust the source of the data, you can use `eval` to parse it as a Javascript array.  This is often considered a security risk, since it can potentially run any code within the string.  Writing a parser might be a better way if the format is simple.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse`. You don't need any external library to parse JSON.

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally
>   transforming the value produced by parsing.

```
jQuery.get('file.txt', function(data) {
  a1=JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(a1);
});
```

Comment: your text file has unescaped `single quote` characters

Comment: It should look like `[[0,\"IN\",2],[2,\"142\",3]]`

Comment: quotes are part of my requirement to treat it as string literal .i want to create an array like this var a=[[1,'IN',2],[2,'GB',3]];

Comment: with this statement a=data;

Comment: your data in file doesnt have a valid JSON. You must have it escaped properly. or there is a workaround if cannot edit the file, replace all single quotes with `\"`

Comment: With this code: `a=JSON.parse(data.replace(/'/g,'\"'))`